# LWUIT tabs, how to make tabs as title of a container?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-tabs

Hi I'm new in LWUIT please help me figure this out, I want to make my tabs to stay in tact when I scroll the list within the container that the Tab houses. For example I have a tab on which I add 3 tabcomponent and these components are containers, the first container has different containers in it, the second container has an HTMLComponent and the third one has a list which contains a lot of element more than 100. When I scroll this list the Tabs disappear as the list moves down, so how do i stop this and make only the list scrollable and the Tabs to be always visible like a title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form.setScrollable(false);
form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);
```

Now when adding a component as a tab make sure it is scrollable.